# node.js:facebook login implementation callback never fired in live server

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I am trying to implement Facebook login using passport it works fine in development environment but when deploy to Ubuntu callback never fired.

```
passport.use('facebook',new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID:local.facebook.clientId,
        clientSecret:local.facebook.secret,
        callbackURL:local.facebook.callbackurl,
        profileFields: ['id', 'email','name','displayName','picture.type(large)']
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //this never fired in live server
});
```

I have added callback URL in Facebook app settings

Comment: Callback? You mean the redirect back to the app from the Facebook login dialog, right? What happens instead?

Comment: issue is resolved its the problem with redirect URL